# Auto calculation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            var form = document.forms.myform,
                    qty = form.qty,
                    cost = form.cost,
                    output = form.textbox;

            window.calculate = function () {
                var q = parseInt(qty.value, 10) || 0,
                        c = parseFloat(cost.value) || 0;
                output.value = (q * c).toFixed(2);
            };
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="caltest.php" method="post" name="myform" onkeyup="calculate()">
            <label>Num of PAX :</label>
            <input type="text" name="qty" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cost" value="700" />
            <br/>
            <lable>Total Price: </lable>
            <input type="text" name="textbox" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am doing a simple calculation.Not getting any output.

Comment: wotking fine : https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/kfLa17a5/

Comment: i have tried place in jsfiddle, it work fine... but when i insert this into my netbeans, it dose not give me any output

Comment: do u get any error? @user3230289

Comment: wrap your code with load method

Comment: write js code in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: That implies using jquery() (or something very similar), not a bad choice imho, but it's not in the question ;-) @debin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `var form = document.forms.myform` is executed, there is no `<form name="myform"` ...yet.
The simplest (though maybe not the most sophisticated) solution is to move the `<script>` block from `<head>` to *after* the form code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one is working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="caltest.php" method="post" name="myform" onkeyup="calculate()" >
            <label>Num of PAX :</label>
            <input type="text" name="qty" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cost" value="700" />
            <br/>
            <lable>Total Price: </lable>
            <input type="text" name="textbox" />
      </form>    
      <script>
            var form = document.forms.myform,
                    qty = form.qty,
                    cost = form.cost,
                    output = form.textbox;

            window.calculate = function () {
                var q = parseInt(qty.value, 10) || 0,
                        c = parseFloat(cost.value) || 0;
                output.value = (q * c).toFixed(2);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```